# vector<vector<T>> vs T [][]?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

i have a code which works almost 7-8 times faster with 2D array instead of vector<vector>.

i am only adding more text because it asks me to make it wordy.

as far as i understand vector<vector> keep pointer where 2D arrays get decomposed to 1D array at compile time. and memory addresses are resolved at compile time. but i am not sure exactly why is there so much difference.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
 
// #define STL__USE

#ifdef STL__USE
  string s;             // runtime: Elapsed time : 8304ms
  vector<vector<bool>> vis(7, vector<bool>(7,false));
#else
  char s[50] = {0};
  bool vis[7][7] = {0}; // runtime: Elapsed time : 1173ms
#endif

/*
Input : ????????????????????????????????????????????????
*/
 


int search (int id, int i, int j,char ch) {
  vis[i][j] = true;
  if (i == 6 && j == 0) {
    return (id == 48);
  }
  bool U, D, R, L;
  U = D = R = L = false;
  if (j != 0 && ch != 'R') L = !vis[i][j-1];  //checking if left move available
  if (j != 6 && ch != 'L') R = !vis[i][j+1];  //checking if right move available
  if (i != 0 && ch != 'D') U = !vis[i-1][j];  //checking if up move available
  if (i != 6 && ch != 'U') D = !vis[i+1][j];  //checking if down move available
  if ((!R && !L && U && D) || (R && L && !D && !U)) return 0; //discarding splits in movements.
  int ans = 0;
  if ((s[id] == '?' || s[id] == 'L') && L) ans += search (id+1, i, j-1, 'L'),vis[i][j-1] = false;
  if ((s[id] == '?' || s[id] == 'R') && R) ans += search (id+1, i, j+1, 'R'),vis[i][j+1] = false;
  if ((s[id] == '?' || s[id] == 'D') && D) ans += search (id+1, i+1, j, 'D'),vis[i+1][j] = false;
  if ((s[id] == '?' || s[id] == 'U') && U) ans += search (id+1, i-1, j, 'U'),vis[i-1][j] = false;
  return ans;
}
void solve() {
  cin >> s;
  cout << search (0,0,0,'.');
}
 
int main () {
  auto start=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  cout.tie(NULL);
  int test = 1;
  //cin >> test;
  for (int t = 1; t <= test; t++) solve();
  auto end=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  cerr << "Elapsed time : " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << "ms\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: What optimization settings are you using in your compiler? Does the disparity persist if you set `test` to higher than `1`?

Comment: `vector<bool>` is notoriously slow, because it does packing internally.

Comment: Your understanding seems to be incorrect. Whatever you meant by "vector<vector> keep pointer where 2D arrays get decomposed to 1D array at compile time" nothing like that happens.

Comment: i am using simple g++ 9.4 compiler without any optimizer.

Comment: Note that `std::vector<bool>` is a *specialization* of the normal `std::vector` template. It stores the boolean values in a space-compact way, which of course means there needs to be extra operations to handle the boolean values (packing bits into larger elements and unpacking them again).

Comment: `std::array<std::array<bool, 7>, 7>` would be a more accurate comparison.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh C++ is meant to be compiled with optimisation. A lot of its features (like `std::vector`) introduce some overhead which is expected to be eliminated during compilation, but that requires the you allow the compiler to optimize those costs away. It isn't generally meaningful to compare the performance of unoptimized builds.

Comment: `STL__USE` name is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it, ypur program will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes that is taking similar time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh thanks i didn't knew about that i will sure learn about compiler optimizations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, _exactly that_ happens. A `vector<vector<bool>>` is more comparable to a `(bool*)[7]` than a `bool[7][7]`, and that's literally why it's slower. Apparently it is your understanding that is incorrect.

Comment: @eerorika _"`STL__USE` name is reserved to the language implementation"_ Is it?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Since this is unoptimized, there are probably other costs, like `operator[]` requiring an extra function call, and possibly extra checks if the library implementer decided to put in extra checks suck as for out-of-range indexes. Double indirection hurts, but it may or may not be the dominant reason for the loss of performance.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings All identifiers with double underscore anywhere in them are reservered. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: @eerorika not sure but it didn't gave any warnings or anything.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Perhaps, but that's trivial to resolve: the fact remains that the inescapable problem here is the poor scale and locality of nested vectors.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm TIL; thought it was just leading underscores.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh absence of warnings is not a proof of correctness. Compilers are not required nor guaranteed to warn about undefined behaviour.

Comment: ... and, crucially, it is often intractible for them to do so, and this is often _why_ it's deemed UB by the standard rather than a diagnosable error.

Answer (score 4):

1. `vector<bool>` was a screwup.  They decided way back that it should be packed bits.  This makes it not actually match the concept of "container", and causes headaches all over the place.
2. a `vector<vector<?>>` is akin to a `X* arr[]`, not an `X arr[][]`.  The vector of vectors is a jagged array, not a rectangular one.

There are two solutions.

`std::array<7, std::array<7, bool>>` is perfectly sensible.  It packs up just like `bool arr[7][7]` but has all of the utility of a `std` container.

Another option is `std::vector<char> buff(49);`, then doing custom indexing.  `char` because `vector<bool>` is packed bits, and `49` because a `[7][7]` array is contiguous.

Finally, your use of `std::string` appears to be undefined behavior (ie, memory corruption).

Comment: `std::array<7, std::array<7, bool>>` Ahh, nothing like the C++ standard library making simple concepts easy to write. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> as far as i understand `vector<vector>` keep pointer where 2D arrays get decomposed to 1D array at compile time

Pretty much. Bear in mind that each of the 7 elements of your outer vector is just a pointer to some other vector stored elsewhere. All this indirection is poison for your CPU cache, not to mention the 7 unnecessary dynamic allocations and de-allocations.

You'd be better off with a single `vector<bool>` of size *7×7*. You'll have to fake the 2D indexing into this data buffer, but that's easy (*i = 7×y + x*). It's worth it to have all your `bool`s in one contiguous place, as they are with your array.

Also, don't forget to build with "optimisations" *enabled* (e.g. `-O2`) to avoid unnecessary inefficiencies with `operator[]` calls and so forth (though such things are a fixed overhead, not a scale problem).

Comment: another problem is `vector<bool>` specialization. You should at least mention this in the answer. It's a big source of performance issue.

Comment: There is an additional concern regarding `std::vector<bool>` specifically, because it packs 8 elements to a byte. It has a significant impact on accessing individual elements even if they are contiguous. `operator[]` returns a proxy object which requires indirection and bitshifting to actually read or write anything.

Comment: The bitshifting for packed bools is not going to cause the 7-8x perf problem OP is reporting.  That's nearly all from the jagged array of vector objects.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I tend to ignore that because it's a fixed overhead and frankly I don't subscribe to the cargo cult hate of `std::vector<bool>` as much as some do, though I'll grant you that at this scale it could approach being noticeable, and given the OP's access pattern it could approach being a bottleneck. I sincerely doubt that the finished, optimised program will have any untoward indirection from that proxy object though.